Streaming Node.js canvas via WebRTC with simple-peer
I was wondering if there is a way to capture a stream from a canvas in Node.js like in the browser using canvas.captureStream()?
I am using the "canvas" library for Node.js and there is no function to do this.
My goal is to send this stream to the browser via WebRTC using "simple-peer".
